# Parse Push Notification Not Working In Production

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, push-notification, parse-platform

I'm using the Parse SDK to send pushes to my app, it works fine in Dev or a local build, but when I push to my devices in production, the push never is received.

Has anyone encountered this issue? On the parse website it has a status of done on push itself.

Comment: Have you add distribution certificate to parse?

Comment: @Maul Wait, are there instructions on how to make a Production certificate as opposed to just a Development?

Comment: In Setting section of your app in parse there is a push notification setting check there. There must be your distribution certificate.

Comment: @Maul I double checked, and the production certificate is there. What else could it be?

Comment: check your client Push is enable or not

Answer (score 0):

MAke sure that you are sending your pushes to

`gateway.push.apple.com:2195`

instead of 
    gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195

also check if your provisioning profile is contains

```
<key>aps-environment</key>
<string>production</string>
```

by opening the .mobileprovision file as a text file